# Java: Extending a class, constructor of subclass gives error

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

A little background:

There are three classes involved: `Tester(main method)`, `DNASequence(object)` and `ProteinDNA(subclass of DNASequence)`. All three are under the same package.

The constructor for `ProteinDNA` accepts an object `DNASequence` and an integer

```
public class ProteinDNA extends DNASequence{
public ProteinDNA(DNASequence dna, int startAt){   //this is the constructor
```

Compiling the class `ProteinDNA` gives me an error at the constructor.

The error in Eclipse is:

```
"Implicit super constructor `DNASequence()` is undefined.
 Must explicitly invoke another constructor"
```

The error in jGrasp is:

```
ProteinDNA.java:16: error: 
   constructor DNASequence in class DNASequence cannot be applied to given types;
public ProteinDNA(DNASequence dna, int startAt)^{


     required: String

     found: no arguments

     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"
```

What am I doing wrong? The Tester class feeds the `ProteinDNA` with an appropriately constructed instance of `DNASequence`.

Comment: `ProteinDNA` _is a_ `DNASequence`, so you need to call `DNASequence` constructor explicitly as it appears it doesn't have a no-arg constructor.

Comment: You'll find an answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143317/java-inheritance-error-implicit-super-constructor-is-undefined

Comment: Creating a no-arg constructor in DNASequence fixes the issue! Thank you!

Comment: @user1766889: Well it'll fix the compile-time error - but it may not actually do what you want. Are you sure that `ProteinDNA` should extend `DNASequence`? It seems odd for it to accept one in its constructor *and* extend it...

Comment: It isn't too odd because the second argument is an int which is the index on the DNASequence. So ProteinSequence is only a part of the DNASequence class. It's not like I'm copying an entire instance of the superclass into an instance of the subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Parent Class DNASequence has existing constructor with parameters. There 2 solutions for this.
```

1)    You can add default no argument constructor to DNA Sequence  class.

2)    Modify child class constructor to invoke parent class constructor like below,

```
    public ProteinDNA(DNASequence dna, int startAt){

   super(....); // This should be the 1st line in constructor code, add parameters 
                as per parent constructor 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to pass a DNASequence object and that the thing that is failing is the building of that object.

> required: String
>   found: no arguments

This makes me think that you probably try to do somthing like the following:

```
new ProteinDNA(new DNASequence(), num);
```

And the compiler says that it expects a String instead:

`new ProteinDNA(new DNASequence("SOME STRING"), num);`

Does that make sense?

Maybe we could be more helpful if you post some specific code, namely:

- ProteinDNA constructor invocation
- DNASequence constructors signatures
- Test method's code

Also, can you clarify why, if ProteinDNA is a subclass of DNASequence, you are passing a DNASequence to its constructor? Is that some kind of defensive copy?

Also, as mentioned in alternative answer, you might want to add the call to the super constructor (`DNASequence(String)`) to the child constructor, as first line, like this:

```
super("SOME STRING")
```

But that really depends on your logic...