# What is Implicit constructors on Java

Tags: java, c++

Is it mandatory to call base class constructor in Java?
In C++ it was optional, so I am asking this.

When I extend `ArrayAdapter`, I get this error: `"Implicit super constructor ArrayAdapter<String>() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor"`

So, what is the purpose of calling base constructor? When I create object base class constructor will call & then it comes to derived right.

Comment: You may not have a rrayAdapter<String>() constructor. If you add a default constructor in the base class, it should be fine.

Comment: Related : [Java error: Implicit super constructor is undefined for default constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197634/java-error-implicit-super-constructor-is-undefined-for-default-constructor).

Comment: So, is it some thing like DerivedClass(int x, int y): BaseClass(y), in c++???. right?? Also one more doubt, in the above mechanism, base class constructor class twice or once?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The no-args constructor is called implicitly if you don't call one yourself, which is invalid if that constructor doesn't exist. The reason it is required to call a super constructor is that the superclass usually has some state it expects to be in after being constructed, which may include private variables that can't be set in a sub-class. If you don't call the constructor, it would leave the object in a probably invalid state, which can cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: So, is it some thing like DerivedClass(int x, int y): BaseClass(y), in c++???. right??

Also one more doubt, in the above mechanism, base class constructor class twice or once?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Java only allows you to call one constructor in a constructor, either a base class or forwarding to another constructor in the current class, so the base class constructor can only be called once.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to call the no-args constructor of super class. If you want to call a constructor with args, user **super** keyword like show below:

```
super(arg1, ...);
```

Comment: "It's not necessary to call the no-args constructor of the super class," but will Java insert a call anyway?

Comment: @AndrewMcKinlay Yes, unless the user code starts with `this(...)`.