# I am very confusion to usage of explicit constructors in java

Tags: java

In what situation we implement the explicit constructors in java program and when we doesn't need to implement explicit constructors.

Comment: welcome to SO. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please put an example, what do you think this behaviour should be and the behaviour that you have seen.

Comment: In regards - typically SO is not for "please give me code". Also similar questions have already been answered, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265311/what-is-implicit-constructors-on-java

Comment: You need to implement explicit constructors when you need to use them.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.javatpoint.com/constructor) explains the full story. In short: **you need explicit constructors if you want to pass parameters** to this constructor. If you do not need this, you can either provide a "parameterless" constructor ( `public Foo() {}` ), or you do nothing, in which case the system will create an empty one for you in the background.