# Implicit super constructor Num() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor, what is the logic behind this

Tags: java, object, oop, constructor

```
class Num 
{
    Num(double x) 
    { 
        System.out.println( x ) ; 
    }
}
class Number extends Num 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        Num num = new Num(2) ; 
    } 
}
```

In the above program, its show the error. Please help me out.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197634/java-error-implicit-super-constructor-is-undefined-for-default-constructor

Comment: Just add a no arg constructor to Num

Comment: But the main question here is WHY ARE YOU DOING THIS? It makes no sense at all...

Comment: @tobias_k I dont see Number as nested class

Comment: @AbhinavKumar You are right, just misleading indentation (now edited).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you define your own constructor,the compiler does not provide a no-argument constructor for you.
When you define a class with no constructor,the compiler inserts a no-arg constructor for you with a call to super().

```
class Example{
}
```

becomes

```
class Example{

Example(){
super();   // an accessible no-arg constructor must be present for the class to compile.
}
```

However,it is not the case with your class as Number class cannot find a no-arg constructor for Num class.You need to explicity define a constructor for you with a call to any of the super constructor

Solution:-

```
class Num 
{
    Num(double x) 
    { 
        System.out.println( x ) ; 
    }
}

class Number extends Num 
{ 


 Number(double x){
 super(x);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        Num num = new Num(2) ; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is defined for class `double`, yet you call Num with an integer argument. Integers aren't automatically promoted to doubles, and you have no default constructor, therefore you get a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

as Asalynd provide the asnswer of this question correctly.
Your constructor is defined for class double, yet you call Num with an integer argument. Integers aren't automatically promoted to doubles, and you have no default constructor, therefore you get a compilation error. you have to type cast before passing the argument in constructor