# Minecraft modding block constructer error

Tags: minecraft-forge

I'm making a mod, and I am getting an error(no duh) and I have tried searching it up but I want an answer specific to my problem because I am not very good at this. I am getting this error in my block class.

Implicit super constructor Block() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

and I don't know how to fix it. Please Help its for a project.

block class:

```
package GDMCrocknrollkid.fandomcraft;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;

public class BlockCbBlock extends Block {

protected BlockCbBlock(Material material) {
    super(material);
}

}
```

mod class:

```
    package GDMCrocknrollkid.fandomcraft;

    import net.minecraft.block.Block;
    import net.minecraft.item.Item;
    import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
    import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
    import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
    import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
    import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
    import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;

    @Mod(modid = "fc", name = "Fandomcraft", version = "1.0")
    public class fandomcraft {

    public static Item itemCbIngot;
    public static Block blockCbBlock;

    @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event){
        //Item/Block initialization and registering
        //Config Handling
        itemCbIngot = new ItemCbIngot().setUnlocalizedName("ItemCbIngot").setTextureName("fc:itemCbIngot"); //item.itemCbIngot.name
        blockCbBlock = new BlockCbBlock(Material.iron);




        GameRegistry.registerItem(itemCbIngot, itemCbIngot.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event){
        //Proxy, TileEntity, entity, GUI and Packet Registering
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error pertains to all of java, not just minecraft forge. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197634/java-error-implicit-super-constructor-is-undefined-for-default-constructor) for some more reference. There are a couple possible reasons for this error. It is most likely 1, but 2 and 3 can be a contributing factor to the error.

1. Your BlockCbBlock Class declares a constructor that is not the default, no-argument constructor that the compiler would otherwise provide (that is, if the Block class doesn't have a constructor) and, if in fact the `Block` class is using the default constructor, then you can't call `super()` on the arguements because the `Block` class uses a constructor with no arguments. Because of this, if you wanted to modify the `Block` constructor, it would be safier and easier to create a custom construcotr inside of the `BlockCbBlock` class itself.
2. You are trying to inherit the constructor of `Block`, but you have declared it as protected, when the constructor in your class should be `public` to match the inherited .
3. If you're using Eclipse, it can give this error when you have your project setup incorrectly (system configuration mismatch)
4. Probably not directly realted to this specific error, but a possible cause of other errors in the near future; you are using the annotation `@EventHandler`, but you have not actually declared the forge event handler.
5. You don't actually register the block for some reason. Even if you're using the block as a recipe item, you still need to register it

To fix potential problems 1, 2, and 4, try this (obtained from [here](http://www.wuppy29.com/minecraft/1-8-tutorial/updating-1-7-to-1-8-part-3-basic-blocks/)):

```
package GDMCrocknrollkid.fandomcraft;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;

private final String name = "BlockCbBlock";
public class BlockCbBlock extends Block {
    public BlockCbBlock() {
        super(Material.iron);
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(this, name);
        setUnlocalizedName(Reference.MODID + "_" + name);
        setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock);
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This way, you'll declare its `UnlocalizedName`, `Material`, and `CreativeTab` ahead of time. This method might be unnecessary, but its a good precaution to help prevent the error. Now, all you have to do is declare it like this:

```
//You need to make your own EventHandler class. Search online for that.
FCEventHandler handler = new FCEventHandler();
@EventHandler
public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event){
    //Config Handling
    //event handler registry
    FMLCommonHandler.instance().bus().register(handler);
    MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(handler);
    //the same thing can be similarly done with this if you wish    
    itemCbIngot = new ItemCbIngot().setUnlocalizedName("ItemCbIngot").setTextureName("fc:itemCbIngot"); 
    blockCbBlock = new BlockCbBlock();
    GameRegistry.registerItem(itemCbIngot, itemCbIngot.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
}
```

Comment: #4 is not applicable. The @EventHandler annotation is part of Forge. `import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler` and denotes the Forge Mod Lifecycle Events, which are the `FMLPreInitializationEvent`, `FMLInitializationEvent`, and `FMLPostInitializationEvent` and searched for on any class annotated with @Mod