# Java - Why does this initializing not work?

Tags: java, class, initialization

This is my code

```
class TestResepter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Legemiddel legemiddel = new Legemiddel("Ibuton", 200, 30.5);
        Lege lege = new Lege("Petter");
        Militærresepter militærresepter = new Militærresepter();
        Presepter presepter = new Presepter();
        BlaaResepter blaaresepter = new BlaaResepter();
        Resept resept=new Resept(legemiddel, lege, 650, 21);
    }
}
```

`Legemiddel`, `Lege`, `Militærresepter`, `Presepter`, `BlaaResepter` and `Resept` are other `classes`. However, I get this error:

```
testresepter.java:3: error: constructor Legemiddel in class Legemiddel cannot be applied to given types;
    Legemiddel legemiddel=new Legemiddel("Ibuton", 200, 30.5);
                          ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String,int,double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
testresepter.java:4: error: constructor Lege in class Lege cannot be applied to given types;
    Lege lege=new Lege("Petter");
              ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
testresepter.java:8: error: constructor Resept in class Resept cannot be applied to given types;
    Resept resept=new Resept(legemiddel, lege, 650, 21);
                  ^
  required: no arguments
  found: Legemiddel,Lege,int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
3 errors
```

Why is that? What do I have to do to make it work?

This is the class Legemiddel

```
class Legemiddel {
    static int Id=-1;
    static String navnet;
    static double prisen;
    static double virkestoffet;

    public static void main(String navn, double pris, double virkestoff) {
        Id++;
        navnet = navn;
        prisen = pris;
        virkestoffet=virkestoff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Legemiddel` constructor (not posted) doesn't take any arguments. Call `new Legemiddel();` (no arguments).

Comment: [The Java Tutorials - Providing Constructors for Your Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: If you look at the edited version, I have posted Legemiddel. So I think the question is how do I implement the params, if not as above?

Answer (score 2):

As of now, your class `Legemiddel` doesn't have a constructor that takes 3 arguments. I think you're confusing how to create a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) and how to write a `main` method.

You're calling `new Legemiddel("Ibuton", 200, 30.5);`, so your class should have a constructor that looks like this:

```
public Legemiddel(String navn, double pris, double virkestoff) {
    ...
}
```

Also, another potential source of error is, that you probably want to have **instance variables** instead of all `static` **class variables**. Otherwise, when you're creating multiple instances of `Legemiddel`, it would change all values of all previous created instances.

For example:

```
Legemiddel l1 = new Legemiddel("Test", 10, 20);
Legemiddel l2 = new Legemiddel("Oops", 0, 0);

System.out.println(l1.Id); // Would print 1 instead of 0
System.out.println(l1.navnet); // Would print Oops instead of Test
System.out.println(l1.prisen); // Would print 0.0 instead of 10.0
System.out.println(l1.virkestoffet); // Would print 0.0 instead of 20.0
```

So your class should instead look like

```
class Legemiddel {
    private static int ID_GEN = -1;

    private final int id;
    private final String navnet;
    private final double prisen;
    private final double virkestoffet;

    public Legemiddel(String navn, double pris, double virkestoff) {
        id = ++ID_GEN;
        navnet = navn;
        prisen = pris;
        virkestoffet = virkestoff;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getNavnet() {
        return navnet;
    }
    public double getPrisen() {
        return prisen;
    }
    public double getVirkestoffet() {
        return virkestoffet;
    }
}
```

`ID_GEN` is now a **class variable**, which is "shared" among all instances of `Legemiddel`. In this case it is desirable, because you want to have a common generator for each instance that retains its state between different instantiations. If you want each instance to have its own id though, you need a separate **instance variable** `id`, that is not shared, but unique to each instance.

All other fields should be **instance variables** (no `static`), i.e. they belong to one and only one instance. If they remain `static` you'll run into trouble when creating multiple instances of `Legemiddel`, because they would share the same values of `navnet`, `prisen` and `virkestoffet` across all instances like I've shown in the code before.

Now, with the changed class, you don't have this kind of behaviour anymore:

```
Legemiddel l1 = new Legemiddel("Test", 10, 20);
Legemiddel l2 = new Legemiddel("Oops", 0, 0);

System.out.println(l1.getId()); // Prints 0
System.out.println(l1.getNavnet()); // Prints "Test"
System.out.println(l1.getPrisen()); // Prints 10.0
System.out.println(l1.getVirkestoffet()); // Prints 20.0
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) you can read more about class members.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement Legemiddel constructor with given 3 params :)

Comment: If you look at the edited version, I have posted Legemiddel. So I think the question is how do I implement the params, if not as above?

Comment: Replace `static void main` by Legemidel, that is the constructor. And remove all `static`

Comment: I have tried that, but then the subclasses that extends Legemiddel doesnt work

Comment: @pkrist instead of randomly trying stuff you should probably read up on how constructors work and understand that befor continuing. I provided you a link to the oracle tutorial but there are dozens of good tutorials all over the internet.

Comment: I have read it, and made it work. But it says nothing about subclasses, and if I use class Legemiddel{public Legemiddel{}} it works, bur the subclasses extending the class Legemiddel dont. Cant find anything on Oracle about subclasses

Comment: @pkrist [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/summaryinherit.html). I stopped because I found three. I could find more. But you should work on your searching.

Comment: This might help: [Java error: Implicit super constructor is undefined for default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197634/java-error-implicit-super-constructor-is-undefined-for-default-constructor)